# Merging multiple rows from a csv into a single row

Tags: sql, csv

I've been given a bunch of contacts in csv format like so:

```
companyID, companyName, contactId, firstName, lastName, email
```

And asked to merge all the contacts from a single company into a single row like so

```
companyID, companyName, contactId, firstName, lastName, email, companyName, contactId, firstName, lastName, email...
```

As to why they want the data like this, I have no idea.

I'm not tied to any particular technology as long as it's freely available and I get the right result. How would you achieve this?

So far I tried importing into a postgres table and attempting various joins and recursive queries but I can't quite come up with the right syntax.

Comment: What's the backend? When you write "contacts in csv format" is that in a column or a file? Does this have to be in SQL or can it be solved using client software? What client software can you target?

Comment: i think the way to handle this is in the application, not w/sql. Just get the data and write to file, just keep all the data on the same line for each company.

Comment: wouldn't bother with sql for this. Not my area of expertise but Perl would be a standout candidate, probably do it in one line...

Comment: pretty much any language (besides SQL) will suit you for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to Unix/Linux or CygWin on Windows, you could use

```
sort csvFileName | awk -F, 'BEGIN {last="";} {if (last == $1) { printf ","; } else { printf "\n"; }; printf $0; last =$1; }'
```

This would repeat the CompanyID each times but you can alter the printf 0$ to output columns other than $1 or you could post process to remove those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution:

1. Create a Contact class to hold all the info for one contact.
2. Create a Company class to hold the info for one company.
3. Create a `Map<Company, List<Contact>>` to map contacts to a company.
4. Read the file, populating Company and Contact objects and the `List<Contact>` for each company.
5. Iterate through the keySet of the map.  For each map entry, output the company and contact info.

[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) might be helpful.

If you don't find an open source CSV reader, you can split the line based on comma (,) and in the Company and Contact classes, just implement something like `public String toCSV()` class to output the object as a CSV.

Comment: that's way more complicated then it needs to be, no need for OOP here